# Can someone double check my time complexity/space bigO

Tags: algorithm, time, structure, space

I have to write pseudocode for a class on going through an array and checking for duplicates. I would love some feedback on my time complexity and time cost. I am pretty sure I am doing most of it correctly.

The only one I am worried about is the third block of code being O(n^3), I know insertion sort is O(n^2) worst case and you must go through the array again which would be O(n) so combining that with O(n^2) would result in O(n^3) or no? If not could someone please explain when I know that the time cost will be O(n^x) x being whatever number

```
Alg mostFreq(file)
input: file name
output: print the word and how many times it appears

//count words
Map<string, int> map

while reading word from file 
    strip word // to lower / remove symbols/numbers
    count = map.get(word)
    if (count == null) count = 1
    freq.put(word, 1 + count)


//find max counted word 
maxCount = 0
maxCountWord = ""
for (Entry<string, int> entry: map.entrySet())
    if (entry.getValue() > maxCount0 
        maxWord = entry.getKey()
        maxCount = entry.getValue()

//print
print("Most frequent word is " + maxWord + " occurs " + maxCount + " times")

//time cost: O(n)
```

-

```
Alg hasDuplicates(A, n)
input: A is an array of data with size n
output: if A has nay two duplicate values, return true, otherwise return false

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (j != i)
            if (A[i] == A[j]) return true

return false

//Space cost: O(n) 
//Time cost: O(n^2)
```

-

```
Alg hasDuplicates(A, n)
input: A is an array of data with size n
output: if A has nay two duplicate values, return true, otherwise return false

//insertionSort  TimeComplexity O(n^2)
for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    cur = A[i]
    j = i -1
    while (j >= 0 and A[j] > cur)
        A[j + 1] = A[j]
        j = j - 1
    A[j + 1] = cur  

//Look for duplicate
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    if (A[i] == A[i+1]) return true

return false

//Space cost: O(n)
//Time cost: O(n^3)
```

-

```
Alg hasDuplicates(A, n)
input: A is an array of data with size n
output: if A has nay two duplicate values, return true, otherwise return false

Map<int, int> map
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (map.containsKey(A[i]) return true
    else map.put(A[i], 0)

return false

//Space cost: O(n)
//Time cost: O(n)
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: The time complexity of the insertionSort is `O(n^2+n)` which can be simplified as `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Is that in general, or including going through the array again after the sort? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
Alg hasDuplicates(A, n)
input: A is an array of data with size n
output: if A has nay two duplicate values, return true, otherwise return false

//insertionSort  TimeComplexity O(n^2)
for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    cur = A[i]
    j = i -1
    while (j >= 0 and A[j] > cur)
        A[j + 1] = A[j]
        j = j - 1
    A[j + 1] = cur  

//Look for duplicate
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    if (A[i] == A[i+1]) return true

return false

//Space cost: O(n)
//Time cost: O(n^3)
```

It is O(n^2 + n) = O(n^2), your look-up loop is outside the insertion sort loop, which should use "add" instead of "multiply".

```js
Alg hasDuplicates(A, n)
input: A is an array of data with size n
output: if A has nay two duplicate values, return true, otherwise return false

Map<int, int> map
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (map.containsKey(A[i]) return true
    else map.put(A[i], 0)

return false

//Space cost: O(n)
//Time cost: O(n)
```

For the mapping, I think `containsKey()` and `put()` should be O(lg n)?
So it is O(n lg n) instead of O(n)